# How to do rotation around control's center in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want do rotate button to 90 degrees but it gets clipped because it rotates arount (0,0). How to make it rotate around center if I don't know it't width in pixels (it's a template for many buttons)

Comment: Are you using the RenderTransform or the LayoutTransform?  A 90 degree LayoutTransform seems to work ok for me even without specifying the origin.

Comment: I'm using LayoutTransform and button is in `Grid` with column width set to auto. Correct rotation doesn't work anyway because it seems that grid sets column width equal to button's width inseatd of height.

Comment: too big to post in comment. uploaded to http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=22752&c=9980825

Comment: A lot going on in your XAML!  Are you sure the LayoutTransform is the problem?  What is the button on the gridsplitter supposed to do/show?

Comment: This button is supposed to collapse one side of `GridSplitter`. Just try to set column width from `auto` to `28` and to play with `LayoutTransform`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
<Button ...>
  <Button.LayoutTransform>
    <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="90"/>
  </Button.LayoutTransform>
</Button>
```

Comment: this one did not work for me in windows phone 8 .NET 4.5 C# XAML Application. The one by @FrancescoDeVittori worked though.

Comment: this only moves the button to the right and to the buttom by 0.5 each
this seems not to be the correct answer (VS17 .Net 6.4.1)

Answer (score 142):

You have to set the control's RenderTransformOrigin to 0.5, 0.5.

ex.:

```
<Button RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
    <RepeatButton.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </RepeatButton.RenderTransform>
</RepeatButton>
```

Comment: This one works for me, though the accepted answer doesn't. Maybe there's a difference here between RenderTransform and LayoutTransform?

Comment: Yeah this works for me as well, not accepted answer.

Comment: LayoutTransform from the accepted answer changes everything around the element I'm trying to spin.  setting the RenderTransformOrigin and using RenderTransform work great, thanks!

Comment: I had a problem with this solution, as it rotated but kept the original layout spacing. The LayoutTransform solution (accepted solution) properly calculated the space for the element.

Comment: This IS the answer. Please can the author review!

Comment: This works for UWP apps while the accepted answer does not.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that the origin isn't relevant with a LayoutTransform.

MSDN says:

> Setting a transform provides powerful capabilities of scaling and
>   rotating. However, LayoutTransform ignores TranslateTransform
>   operations. This is because the layout system behavior for child
>   elements of a FrameworkElement auto-corrects any offsets to the
>   position of a scaled or rotated element into the layout and coordinate
>   system of the parent element.

and the following "correctly" rotates the button.

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">Excessively Long Button Still Ok
        <Button.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </Button.LayoutTransform>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```