# WPF image control and jpg rotation metadata

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having some trouble with `Image` control in WPF.

I have one jpg file, which loads with wrong rotation and even i rotate this picture in windows (right click and `rotate left/right`) there is no change in application.

Seems that there are some EXIF metadata in the image, which gets rotated together with a wrong image.

I'm reading the image from www so I do not have local file (and I don't want to have it). Here's how I'm converting `byte[]` to `BitmapImage`:

```
public static BitmapImage BitmapImageFromByteArray(Byte[] bytes)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    image.StreamSource = stream;
    image.EndInit();
    stream.Close();
    stream.Dispose();
    return image;
}
```

So there are 2 ways of handling that:

1. Set `Image` control to ignore EXIF metadata
2. Remove EXIF metadata from `BitmapImage`

Can you help me with handling any of these?

Comment: As a note, you don't need to call `stream.Close()` and `stream.Dispose()` at the same time. One is enough. Even better, use a `using` block, which automatically disposes the stream, like `using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes)) { ... }`.

Comment: I know, this code is after tons of tries so it's not optimized :)

Comment: Did you try out the code on the link I posted or what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code sample on the following link.

**Remove Exif data from image files with C# and WPF libraries:** http://www.techmikael.com/2009/07/remove-exif-data-from-image-files-with.html

Another option may be to use a RotateTransform to rotate the Image element:

[How to do rotation around control's center in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132194/how-to-do-rotation-around-controls-center-in-xaml)